# How to install Red5 on Ubuntu with my vps company OVH

Tags: java, jdk

How do I install Red5 on my ubuntu to support cometchat?
I see some instruction but they don't explain to install Red5 with ubuntu.

- https://support.cometchat.com/documentation/php/admin/plugins/audio-video-chat-plugin/red5-or-fms-rtmp/
- https://support.cometchat.com/documentation/php/installing-cometchat/advanced/installing-red5/

Which Java Script should I choose for Ubuntu/Linux:

```
[root@red5-ubuntu local]# sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
[root@red5-ubuntu local]# sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

I want to install Red5 because I want to use video chat and sreen share with cometchat.

Comment: Either command should do, if you need Java 7. (Also Java and JavaScript are two very different things.)

Comment: The problem that I need to solves now to install Red5 on my ubuntu with command line?

Answer (score 0):

To install Red5 run

```
sudo apt-get install red5-server
```

All needed things (other packages like Java and so on) will be installed automatically.